# Find if method has optional parameters using System.Reflection in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to find a way to know if there is an optional parameter in a method being called and its data types, by using Reflection in VB.Net.
Can someone please explain with an example?

Comment: I know it is C#, but you could easily convert to VB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isoptional?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Kevin You can switch to `vb.net` there. Find `c#` at the top before _Share, _Edit, Save_ and select `vb.net` from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2):

This is really something that you could have figured out by reading the relevant documentation but, regardless, here's an example:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim method = GetType(SomeClass).GetMethod(NameOf(SomeClass.DoSomething))

        For Each parameter In method.GetParameters().Where(Function(pi) pi.IsOptional)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} As {1}", parameter.Name, parameter.ParameterType)
        Next

        Stop
    End Sub

End Module


Public Class SomeClass

    Public Sub DoSomething(p1 As String, Optional p2 As Integer = 0, Optional p3 As Boolean = False)

    End Sub

End Class
```